# Classpath of a file java

Tags: java

I am working on sending email with template using ogham API. 
for sending email , there is a line like -

```
 service.send(new Email
 ("subject", 
 new TemplateContent
 ("classpath:/template/thymeleaf/simple.html", new SimpleBean
 ("foo", 42)), "<recipient address>"));
```

My template stored in -

```
"/src/main/resources/template/parcio/SignupEmailTemplate.html"
```

what will be my classpath?
I already used "/template//parcio/SignupEmailTemplate.html" . and got error

" template might not exist or might not be accessible".

Answer (score 0):

Use the absolute path to locate your file, relative paths are not always relative to the source directory

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("template/parcio/SignupEmailTemplate.html").toString()
```

to acquire path to a file, that is located inside of your **maven resources** folder.